# How to use Pisa on Google App Engine to generate PDF from HTML/CSS

Tags: google-app-engine, pdf, printing, pisa

I'm developing a simple GAE application that crawls some data from a given site and presenst it formatted in html/css.
What I would like to do now is to offer an *Export to PDF feature* trasforming the formatted html/css to PDF.

I've imported Reportlab Toolkit and it works good but it's not what I need since it forces me to create PDF manually like:

```
pcanvas.drawString(10, 10, 'This is the title Blah blah blah')
```

What I really need is a library like [PISA](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/demo) that trasforms Html/Css to PDF.

Anyone has managed to succesfully intregrate and use PISA on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.xhtml2pdf.com itself is hosted on GAE for several years now.

This discussion is about the problems you face on GAE.

http://groups.google.com/group/xhtml2pdf/browse_thread/thread/c002418fe31eef98/366112086b795143

Comment: Thanks for this. Over 2 years later and it's still the best link to the solution. Excluding `.pyc` files seems to be the only real requirement for fixing this.

Comment: I know this post is quite old, but is the xhtml2pdf still hosted on GAE? If not have they replaced it with something similar?

Comment: No, it is not hosted on GAE any more, but should in principle still be possible.